# CSS, style specific or general style properties

Tags: css

This code is longer, but has no change of going wrong, because I specify each property separately.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

This code is shorter, but may run into issues I think, because I overwrite the padding with padding right.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px;
  padding-right:20px;
}
```

Both will work and create the exact same output right?
What is better style of code?

Comment: or `padding:80px 80px 20px`. Well, you have a lot of ways to write the same code, pick what you want

Comment: You could change it to the shorthand version: `padding: 80px 20px 80px 80px` and avoid overriding it. It does the same thing, only shorter